# Bootstrap Navbar-right error

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap classes are not allowing me to pull my items in the div to the right on my navbar. I am following a Django tutorial online and creating a HTML page with bootstrap. Here is my code:

```
<!-- Individual items in the navbar -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topNavBar"> <!-- This makes the collapse three bar button work -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="{% url 'pics:index' %}">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                    Folders
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                    Pictures
                </a>
            </li
        </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </form>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Add Folder
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Logout
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

This should work, and the "Add Folder" and "Logout" buttons should be to the right, but it does not work, and these buttons are right next to the search bar. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Ok, but is missing a end tag in one of the `<li>`

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
              <a href="{% url 'pics:index' %}">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                  Folders
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
              <a href="#">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;
                  Pictures
              </a>
          </li <!--Here--!>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Oh, wow... I guess most coding problems really are in the syntax! Thank you so much :)